# Difficulties compiling document, possibly related to moredefs

Tags: packages, compiling

I'm having a lot of problems compiling a TeX document. Its behaviour appears to be completely random. First it compiled fine. Then it would only compile if divided into chunks. Now it does not compile at all. I do not think I have made any changes to the document (e.g. to the header) that would cause this to happen. Errors seem to vary with each build, but the two key ones (they always come first) appear to be

```
E:\tex\latex\frankenstein\moredefs.sty:798: LaTeX Error: Command \providelength already defined. [}]
E:\tex\latex\frankenstein\moredefs.sty:815: LaTeX Error: Command \providecounter already defined. [}]
```

Here is the header itself, which does not refer to the moredefs package;

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{dialogue}

%*****************************************************


\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I've reloaded Miktex, but that does not work.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Comment: P.S. sorry the above is not a Minimal Worked Example as it refers to external macros. However I've run this as an MWE, and I still get the same error.

Comment: It would only have taken you a minute to fix the MWE, I did it this time.

Comment: I couldn't find the edit button. Now I have it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`memoir` and `moredefs` both define these commands, perhaps the simplest thing is just to undefine memoir's version so the package loading works:

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}

\let\providelength\undefined
\let\providecounter\undefined
\usepackage{dialogue}

%*****************************************************


\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this perfectly safe? Won't memoir need its providelength and providecounter for anything? Or - do we know for certain the definitions are the same?

Comment: @einpoklum they are near enough.